Row will not grow to full width with flexbox and horizontal scrollbar
I'm building a table with flexbox, with the first cell being a header for the row. The other cells in the row are fixed-width.
I'd also like to have a header row with a background than spans the whole width.
Here's what it looks like :

and the corresponding code (using tailwind but it's really a CSS question) :
    <div class="flex flex-col overflow-x-auto p-4">
  <div class="flex w-full bg-gray-300">
    <div class="min-w-40 grow">Header 1</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="min-w-40 grow">Row header 1</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="min-w-40 grow">Row header 2</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex w-full bg-gray-300">
      <div class="min-w-40 grow">Header 2</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="min-w-40 grow">Row header 3</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

Also in tailwind's playground.
When the screen size changes, the extra and removed space is absorbed by the first column, hence the grow class, up to a point, hence the min-w-40 class.
When the screen size gets too small, an horizontal scrollbar appears.
The problem is that the header row's background does no go all the way to the end of the row, it stops before the end.

How do I fix that ? And more importantly, I don't understand why so I'd love an explanation!

Flexbox works for layout in one dimension. Adjacent flex containers are independent. Perhaps Grid layout would be more suitable?

NB: If you add a background colour to your second row, you'll see that they both end at the same point. The flex container doesn't stretch to fit all of its child elements.

The first container is abiding by the grid width of the document. the one below is being pushed beyond the limits by the children with a width applied but the first one does know anything about that.
Had a little play with the below:
<div class="flex flex-col overflow-x-auto p-4">
  <div class="flex bg-gray-300">
    <div class="min-w-40 grow">Header row</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
    <div class="min-w-40 grow">Header cell</div>
    <div class="flex overflow-scroll">
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
      <div class="w-12 flex-none">2.5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

https://play.tailwindcss.com/0zSZt8KTs9
Much better!

Thanks! I think I understand the reason now. Not yet sure how to fix it though. My example is a little too contrived and your solution does not exactly apply. So I edited my code to make it more relevant.
